# Is there any way to rename js object keys using underscore.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

I need to convert a js object to another object for passing onto a server post where the names of the keys differ for example

```
var a = {
    name : "Foo",
    amount: 55,
    reported : false,
    ...
    <snip/>
    ...
    date : "10/01/2001"
    }
```

needs to turn into

```
a = {
  id : "Foo",
  total : 55,
  updated: false,
  ...
  <snip/>
  ... 
  issued : "10/01/2001"
  }
```

where I have lookup obj available for mapping all the keys

```
var serverKeyMap = {
    name : "id",
    amount : "total",
    reported : "updated",
     ...
    date : "issue"
    }
```

Is there a function available in underscore.js or jQuery that I can use that does this functionality?

thanks

Comment: Not underscore, but lodash has [_.mapKeys](https://lodash.com/docs#mapKeys) for modifying keys of an object.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

As far as I know there is no function built into either of these two libraries. You can make your own fairly easily, though: http://jsfiddle.net/T9Lnr/1/.

```
var b = {};

_.each(a, function(value, key) {
    key = map[key] || key;
    b[key] = value;
});
```

Answer (score 76):

I know you didn't mention [lodash](https://lodash.com) and the answers already solve the problem, but someone else might take advantage of an alternative.

As @CookieMonster mentioned in the comments, you can do this with [`_.mapKeys`](https://lodash.com/docs#mapKeys):

```
_.mapKeys(a, function(value, key) {
    return serverKeyMap[key];
});
```

And the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cwkwtgr3/

Comment: The side effects are strong with this one.

Comment: @DFlores009 like what? That would be more helpful.

Answer (score 42):

Similar to @pimvdb, you can also do it with a `_.reduce`:

```
_.reduce(a, function(result, value, key) {
    key = map[key] || key;
    result[key] = value;
    return result;
}, {});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/T9Lnr/39/

Comment: seems to still work for me @wegginho, it prints to the console

Comment: I'm getting an error that underscore is not defined

Comment: underscore is attached as an external resource, perhaps where it's hosted is blocked for you? try opening the file to see if you have access to it

Answer (score 11):

You could copy the values to the new properties with standard JavaScript, and remove the original properties with *omit*, as follows:

```
a.id = a.name;
a.total = a.amount;
a.updated = a.reported;
a = _.omit(a, 'name', 'amount', 'reported');
```

Comment: Please add some explanation. Currently, your answer is flagged "low quality" and might get removed.

Comment: By using this method you can not change all keys with have more than one value.

Answer (score 3):

```
// key_map: {old_name1: new_name1, ... }
function rename_keys(object, key_map, is_picked=false){
  keys = _.keys(key_map);
  new_keys = _.values(key_map);
  picked = _.pick(object, keys);
  renamed = _.object(new_keys, _.values(picked));
  if(is_picked) return renamed;

  return _.chain(object).omit(keys).extend(renamed).value();
}
```

This may be slower than above answers.

Answer (score 2):

No there is no function in either library that explicitly renames keys. Your method is also the fastest (see [jsperf tests](http://jsperf.com/spiny001).) Your best bet, if possible, is to refactor either the client side or server side code so the objects are the same.

Comment: The test cases in the benchmark doesn't even look equal.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use this simple java script ? Value of any key:value pair should be string/number/Boolean.

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
    var serverKeyMap = {
        name : "id",
        amount : "total",
        reported : "updated"
    };

    var a = {
        name : "Foo",
        amount: 55,
        reported : false
    };

    var b={}; // b is object where you will get your output

    for(i in serverKeyMap) b[serverKeyMap[i]]=a[i];

    console.log(b); // It gives what you need.

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I have a transformation operator and would just like to apply it to all keys. I forked pimvdb's fiddle to produce a simple example. In this case it Capitalizes the key. And it dynamically builds the keymap, which I needed to assure works (thanks JSFiddle).

Here is the changed code:

```
var keymap = {};
_.each(a, function(value, key) {
    var oldkey = key;
    key = capitalize(key);
    keymap[oldkey] = key;
});
_.each(a, function(value, key) {
    key = keymap[key] || key;
    b[key] = value;
});
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/mr23/VdNjf/

Comment: Although the example is contrived, in real life I used this to build a  'cleanup' keymap using the first record of a dataset, and then apply it to the rest (which may include additional 'loads' of data).

Comment: i ended up using the _.replace() solution above, but i started by looking at your solution and plunkr. works well. thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's been solved here https://stackoverflow.com/a/30940370/1360897

```
var keyMapping = {'PropertyA': 'propertyA', ..., 'PropertyF': 'propertyNEW'}
```

and also a mapping of old and new values, like this

```
var valueMapping = {'Y': true, 'F': false}
```

And then using _.map and _.transform, you can transform the object, like this

```
var result = _.map(allItems, function(currentObject) {
    return _.transform(currentObject, function(result, value, key) {
        if (key === 'PropertyF' || key === 'PropertyG') {
            value = valueMapping(value);
        }
        result[keyMapping[key]] = value;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As user2387823 was saying [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35719016/1446845)  using **omit** is a great option. For example you could write something like this

```
function updateObjKey(obj, currentKey, newKey) {
    var keyValue = obj[currentKey];
    obj = _.omit(obj, [currentKey]);
    obj[newKey] = keyValue;
    return obj;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

this ES2015/2017 version ‍♂️

```js
function objectMap(source,keyMap) {
    return Object.entries(keyMap).reduce((o,[key , newKey]) => {
            o[newKey]=source[key]
            return o;},{})
}

const obj = {
    name : "Foo",
    amount: 55,
    reported : false,
    date : "10/01/2001"
    }
    
const  serverKeyMap = {
    name : "id",
    amount : "total",
    reported : "updated",
    date : "issue"
    }
    
const result = objectMap(obj,serverKeyMap);

console.log(' =>' , result);
```

> `[Object.entries][1]` is es2017 feture will return object key and
>   value as array
>
> ```
> [["name", "id"],["amount", "total"],...]
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You really don't need underscore/lodash for this ... nowadays anyways (I realize the question was asked 9 years ago, but this question is (still) ranked highly in search results and I came across it today  :-) )

Here's another plain ES2015/2017 version that I like, inspired by @malbarmavi's answer (there's probably a bunch of other plain JS functions out there, but I didn't come across any others in my brief search):

```js
// A general key transform method. Pass it a function that accepts the old key and returns
// the new key.
//
// @example
//   obj = transformKeys(obj, (key) => (
//    key.replace(/\b(big)\b/g, 'little')
//  ))
export function transformKeys(source, f) {
  return Object.entries(source).reduce((o, [key, value]) => {
    o[f(key) || key] = value
    return o
  }, {})
}
 
// Provide an object that maps from old key to new key
export function rekeyObject(source, keyMap) {
  transformKeys(source, key => keyMap[key])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I referred the lodash documentation ans found `mapKeys`
https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#mapKeys

```js
_.mapKeys({ 'a': 1, 'b': 2 }, function(value, key) {
  return key + value;
});
// => { 'a1': 1, 'b2': 2 }
```

this perfectly renames the keys and return an object containing the modified desirable object

Answer (score 0):

Using underscore `omit` and spread operator.

```
a = _.omit({
  ...a,
  id: a.name,
  total: a.amount,
  updated: a.reported,
}, ['name', 'amount', 'reported']);
```

Key assignments below spread operator loads new keys and omit omits the old ones.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your new custom function :

```
lodash.rename = function(obj, keys, newKeys) {
  keys.map((key, index) => {
    if(lodash.includes(lodash.keys(obj), key)) {
      obj[newKeys[index]] = lodash.clone(obj[key], true);
      delete obj[key];
    }
  });
  return obj;
};
```

Or else if you want to edit only one keyName:

```
lodash.rename = function(obj, key, newKey) {
    if(lodash.includes(lodash.keys(obj), key)) {
      obj[newKeys[index]] = lodash.clone(obj[key], true);
      delete obj[key];
    }
  return obj;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Using lodash

```
var obj = _.renameKeys( { 1 : "Geeks",  
            2 : "Computer_Science_Portal" }, 
            { 1 : "g", 2 : "c" });
```

so in your case, you want to apply the serverKeyMap onto object a :

```
var obj = _.renameKeys(a, serverKeyMap);
```

from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/lodash-_-renamekeys-method/

Comment: For clarity: this function is not built into Lodash proper, but a an extension added by the `lodash-contrib` package. Likewise, for Underscore there is a `renameKeys` in Underscore-contrib (which lodash-contrib might be a fork of): http://documentcloud.github.io/underscore-contrib/#renamekeys.