# Remap properties name and values using lodash

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I have this array:

```
aItems = [{
    "PropertyA": "apple",
    "PropertyB": "banana",
    "PropertyC": "dog",
    "PropertyD": "hotdog",
    "PropertyE": "coldcat",
    "PropertyF": "Y",
    "PropertyG": "N"
},
...,
{
    "PropertyA": "this",
    "PropertyB": "is",
    "PropertyC": "json",
    "PropertyD": "code",
    "PropertyE": "wow",
    "PropertyF": "N",
    "PropertyG": "N"
}]
```

I would like use **lodash** to obtain this result:

```
aItems = [{
    "propertyA": "apple",
    "propertyB": "banana",
    "propertyC": "dog",
    "propertyD": "hotdog",
    "propertyE": "coldcat",
    "propertyNEW": true,
    "propertyG": false
},
...,
{
    "propertyA": "this",
    "propertyB": "is",
    "propertyC": "json",
    "propertyD": "code",
    "propertyE": "wow",
    "propertyNEW": false,
    "propertyG": false
}]
```

I want map each property name with other names and change the value for some specific properties.
Can I do it using *lodash*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a mapping of old and new keys, like this

```
var keyMapping = {'PropertyA': 'propertyA', ..., 'PropertyF': 'propertyNEW'}
```

and also a mapping of old and new values, like this

```
var valueMapping = {'Y': true, 'F': false}
```

And then using [`_.map`](https://lodash.com/docs#map) and [`_.transform`](https://lodash.com/docs#transform), you can transform the object, like this

```
var result = _.map(allItems, function(currentObject) {
    return _.transform(currentObject, function(result, value, key) {
        if (key === 'PropertyF' || key === 'PropertyG') {
            value = valueMapping(value);
        }
        result[keyMapping[key]] = value;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 11):

Yes, since lodash v3.8.0 you can remap objects in any way desireable

**ES5 code**

```
var items = [ { oldKey: 'oldValue' /*...*/ } ]

var keyMapping = { oldKey: 'newKey' /*...*/ }
var valueMapping = { oldValue: 'newValue' /*...*/ }

var remapper = function(item){
  return _(item) // lodash chain start
    .mapKeys( function(v, k){ return keyMapping[k] } )
    .mapValues( function(v){ return valueMapping[v] } )
    .value() // lodash chain end
}

var remappedItems = items.map(remapper)
```

**ES2015/ES6 code**

```
let items = [ { oldKey: 'oldValue' /*...*/ } ]

let keyMapping = { oldKey: 'newKey' /*...*/ }
let valueMapping = { oldValue: 'newValue' /*...*/ }

let remapper = item => _(item) // lodash chain start
  .mapKeys( (v, k)=> keyMapping[k] )
  .mapValues( v => valueMapping[v] )
  .value() // lodash chain end

let remappedItems = items.map(remapper)
```

Comment: If you want all the key pairs and only want to change one or two keys and don't want to list all the keys in keyMapping, you can change:   <br/> `.mapKeys( (v, k)=> keyMapping[k] )`   <br/> to <br/>  `.mapKeys( (v, k)=> keyMapping[k] || k)`