# Json formatting by 2 fields

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, group-by

I tried formatting json group by city names with [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chandrashekarthota/zkp3m28b/9/) code.

I am trying to group by the same code with city name and city code. Any logic hint would be helpful.

```
CurrentDataFormat = [{
        "Id": 17,
        "code": "123",
        "cityName": "Los Angeles",
        "cityCode": "LA",
        "startDate": "1/20/2016",
        "endDate": "1/20/2016"
    },

    {
        "Id": 18,
        "code": "456",
        "cityName": "Chicago",
        "cityCode": "CH",
        "startDate": "1/22/2016",
        "endDate": "1/25/2016"
    },

    {
        "Id": 19,
        "code": "789",
        "cityName": "Los Angeles",
        "cityCode": "LA",
        "startDate": "1/13/2016",
        "endDate": "1/21/2016"
    }
]

GroupByJsonFormatData(CurrentDataFormat);

function GroupByJsonFormatData(CurrentDataFormat)
{
var refinedArray = {};

for (i = 0; i < CurrentDataFormat.length; i++) {
    refinedArray[CurrentDataFormat[i].cityName] = refinedArray[CurrentDataFormat[i].cityName] ? refinedArray[CurrentDataFormat[i].cityName] : {};

    refinedArray[CurrentDataFormat[i].cityName].name = CurrentDataFormat[i].cityName;

    refinedArray[CurrentDataFormat[i].cityName].CityData = refinedArray[CurrentDataFormat[i].cityName].CityData ? refinedArray[CurrentDataFormat[i].cityName].CityData : [];
    refinedArray[CurrentDataFormat[i].cityName].CityData.push({
        "Id": CurrentDataFormat[i].Id,
        "code": CurrentDataFormat[i].code,
        "startDate": CurrentDataFormat[i].startDate,
        "endDate": CurrentDataFormat[i].endDate
    });
}

var ExpectedDataFormat = [];

for (singleCityName in refinedArray){
    ExpectedDataFormat.push({'name' : refinedArray[singleCityName].name, 'CityData' : refinedArray[singleCityName].CityData});
};

console.log(ExpectedDataFormat);
document.getElementById("resultPane").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(ExpectedDataFormat, undefined, 2);;
}
```

I also tried to make this code generic by passing column names in parameters.
For example I tried like     GroupByJsonFormatData(CurrentDataFormat, GroupByColumn); and tried to append this parameter column to array like

refinedArray[CurrentDataFormat[i].+GroupByColumn]

but it didnt work at the concatenation level.

Comment: Curious ... what is the end reason for grouping the array in this format?

Comment: to display on UI with ng repeat .

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify code using:

```
refinedArray[CurrentDataFormat[i].cityName] = refinedArray[CurrentDataFormat[i].cityName] || {};
```

instead of

```
refinedArray[CurrentDataFormat[i].cityName] = refinedArray[CurrentDataFormat[i].cityName] ? refinedArray[CurrentDataFormat[i].cityName] : {};
```

Same with array:

```
refinedArray[CurrentDataFormat[i].cityName].CityData = refinedArray[CurrentDataFormat[i].cityName].CityData || [];
```

For generic implementation you can use

```
refinedArray[CurrentDataFormat[i]][GroupByColumn]
```

Answer (score 1):

Lodash could help you:

```
var groupedByCity =  _.groupBy(CurrentDataFormat, "cityName")
```

Maybe you are looking to renaming the keys or something else togheter

go for this [hint](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30940370/735725) or search in [docs](https://lodash.com/docs#groupBy)