# How can I clone a tree structure of an array of objects to another one, changing attributes to the cloned?

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng-tree

How can I clone a tree structure of an array of objects to another one, having different or less attibutes on the cloned one in TypeScript?
For example on this:

```
[
   {
      "name":"root_1",
      "extradata":"whatever",
      "anArray":[
         { "id":1, "value":"test" },
         { "id":1, "value":"test" }
      ],
      "anObject":{ "id":1, "value":"test" },
      "children":[
         {
            "name":"child_1",
            "extradata":"whatever",
            "anArray":[],
            "anObject":{},
            "children":[
               {
                  "name":"root_1",
                  "extradata":"whatever",
                  "anArray":[],
                  "anObject":{},
                  "children":[]
               },
               {
                  "name":"root_1",
                  "extradata":"whatever",
                  "anArray":[],
                  "anObject":{},
                  "children":[]
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "name":"root_2",
      "extradata":"whatever",
      "anArray":[],
      "anObject":{},
      "children":[]
   }
]
```

I need a clone of it but instead of "name" the atribute "label", instad of "extradata" = "key" and without the "anArray" and "anObject". Like this:

```
[
   {
      "label":"root_1",
      "key":"whatever",
      "children":[
         {
            "label":"child_1",
            "key":"whatever",
            "children":[
               {
                  "label":"root_1",
                  "key":"whatever",
                  "children":[]
               },
               {
                  "label":"root_1",
                  "key":"whatever",
                  "children":[]
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "label":"root_2",
      "key":"whatever",
      "children":[]
   }
]
```

I need to clone it, to use it the data format for the primeng tree component.

I am trying with something like

```
this.myTree = tree.map((m, index) => Object.assign({}, {
                                label: m.name,
                                key: m.extradata,
                                children: m.children
                            }));
```

but the children are not following the same shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this by first defining interfaces for the input and output types in question:

```
interface InputTree {
  name: string,
  extradata: string,
  anArray: any[],
  anObject: object,
  children: InputTree[]
}

interface OutputTree {
  label: string,
  key: string,
  children: OutputTree[];
}
```

It looks like your input is an `InputTree[]` by that definition, and you want to produce an `OutputTree[]`.  Trees are recursive, so you should write a `treeMap()` function that operates on an `InputTree[]` and then calls itself recursively on the `children` of each `InputTree` in the array.  Like this:

```
const treeMap = (inputTree: InputTree[]): OutputTree[] => inputTree.map(t => ({
  label: t.name,
  key: t.extradata,
  children: treeMap(t.children)
}));

const actual = treeMap(tree);
```

You can verify that this produces the output you expect:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(expected)===JSON.stringify(actual)); // true
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7#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-tu+J5fFD4cjnzZyaLiK1PINJzLjIr6cYAazMLI9bzFOjQ9jcM5baBHb2-ICgpMC5FMd7VbYMrVI7eyqbMdb3NRZvN8BA5kgHiQADMKKB0ABJSD2pywAAqqHQGMuDDgSAvADmSTyqIJK-sggFJL8GoMJo+hAlBYIbLkDDgMhsBJK2DBPi+76frOgoXlet73vAqSvrhH5oIQxC9uB-6QEBxD1vRkHEFhZEUa+VEoEClqCtaUBwIgn4ALIUParoABQXpRn7Yc+3H4fEACUDDkbAcloECmAAHzwLJSloAAdFQElSQgGD6VJGJ0YgxmXEkLH2SBLyYVOzQMMgaDifaFnGa2KnAD4KkqZagm2vAd6wE4jiut5KC+RZn5hWAQngA4KDGQ44AAVJABSADKqQAHLGX+gHmNe+hSQ6ToiCpGBNUVpXlRBjFVTV0WxQ4oWngA9P1IkuEAA)

Comment: I like your idea with interface and thanks for testing in typescriptlang. In fact the response is coming from ngrx/store and it's already mapped in a model. I didn't get how to use the recursive call to have the result I need though. Can you add it to the example please?

Comment: Add it how?  You can see that the implementation of `treeMap()` calls `treeMap()`, right? inside `inputTree.map(t => ({...})`, you need to set properties in the `...`.  The `label` and `key` properties can just be copied from `t`, but the `children` property is an `InputTree[]` and you need it to be an `OutputTree[]`.  Luckily we're writing a function that converts the former to the latter, so the `children` property becomes `treeMap(t.children)`.

Comment: I had to try it now with the store data and it works fine. Thanks a lot man, really appreciated. I couldn't think such usage and I was losing time with the tree.map((m, index) => Object.assign({},.

Comment: Do you have any idea how can I wrap the OutputTree with:
{
    "data": [
  ]
}

At the end it should be something like this to work: https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/assets/showcase/data/files.json

Comment: Like `const hmm = (inputTree: InputTree[]) => ({ data: treeMap(inputTree) }); hmm(tree);`?

Comment: This hmm variable in your example replacing const treeMap = (inputTree: InputTree[]) somehow? Can you please add this wrapper { "data": [ ] }  to your example in Playground link ?

Comment: Like [this](https://tsplay.dev/GmZvam)?  It's not replacing `treeMap`; it's using it.   These follow-up questions in the comments seem to be outside the scope of the original question, so I'm not sure how much longer I can interact here.  If you have a new problem you might want to start a new question to get more eyes on it.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks again @jcalz for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you can use 3rd party libraries - but have you heard of [loadsh](https://lodash.com)?
There are numerous of examples on how to achieve that (:

[first example](https://gist.github.com/microbial/b99af0a7eb11cb680c14)

[second example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8747561/is-there-any-way-to-rename-js-object-keys-using-underscore-js)

If you cannot use it, I would just [dive](https://github.com/lodash/lodash) into the code and see how they implemented it (:

Comment: Thanks for answering. I 've seen it as a reference in similar questions, but no I cannot use it and from the examples I am not even sure if it works in a tree structure like this.